# Replace Content of yml file using sed having multiple key with same name

Tags: sed, yaml

I want to replace path of each log in yml file, below is my file

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  fields.type: spark
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log

- type: log
  enabled: true
  fields.type: kafka
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
```

I don't have any idea how the replace the value having multiple same type i.e. -type: log
In general for sample file I used the below line:

```
sed -i -e '/^ *ssl:/,/^ *[^:]*:/s/enabled: true/enabled: false/' test2.yaml
```

After changing content it should look like:

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  fields.type: spark
  paths:
    - /var/log/spark/*.log

- type: log
  enabled: true
  fields.type: kafka
  paths:
    - /var/log/kafka/*.log
```

Comment: Your string has no `ssl:`, why use `/^ *ssl:/`?

Comment: this is for sample yml I tried,      ssl: enabled: true

Comment: The format is called YAML, and the recommended file extension has been `.yaml` since 2006. You write you have no idea, but you're trying to use `sed` so you have some idea (although a very bad one). Why `sed` and not an appropriate tool for the job that includes a proper YAML parser, those can address the different sequence elements that are mappings in each of which the key `type` occurs. Instead of some never-going-to-work-properly `sed` example, you better describe what the YAML document should look like after the update.

Comment: @Anthon, I have updated what I need, please check it

Answer (score 0):

You should use a real parser for getting values from YAML, or when updating a YAML file.
`sed` is just not the appropriate tool for such complex operations, especially not if someone migth
insert another key-value pair between your `fields.type` and `paths` line, or append an item to 
the sequence that is the value for paths.

Given your input in file `input.yaml`, having ruamel.yaml installed
(`pip install ruamel.yaml`) and the script:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(sys.stdin)
for item in data['filebeat.inputs']:
    try:
        ft = item['fields.type']
        paths = item['paths']
        for idx, path in enumerate(paths):
            pre, post = path.rsplit('/', 1)
            paths[idx] = pre + '/' + ft + '/' + post
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

you can do:

```
< input.yaml python update.py > output.yaml
```

to get:

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  fields.type: spark
  paths:
  - /var/log/spark/*.log

- type: log
  enabled: true
  fields.type: kafka
  paths:
  - /var/log/kafka/*.log
```

If there are multiple items under `paths`, they all get updated (assuming there is at least one `/` in the path).

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this directly through sed command.
You need to do the YAML parsing and based on your requirement, call the necessary sed commands on the parsed data.